# How to store quantitative and time series data in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Referring to [this use case](https://neo4j.com/blog/analyzing-panama-papers-neo4j/), I have a set of similar data that contain people names and their ownership of companies. However, the ownership is identified by percentages and the numbers change frequently. So I cannot simply record "Tom own X company" but I need "Tom own 50% of X company from 1 Jan 2015 to 6 Jun 2015, 55% from 7 Jun 2015 to 10 Oct 2016"

What is the best way to model the data? Ultimately, is Neo4J a good tool for this type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to consider :Ownership nodes, which represent an owner of a percentage of a company valid during a range in time. Your timestamps will likely need to be indexed.

This can let you perform queries such as:

// find the percentage of ownership in a company at a point of time

```
WITH {params.instant} as instant
MATCH (p:Person{name:'Bob Barker'})-[:Owns]->(o:Ownership)-[:Of]->(:Company{name:'KrispyKreme'})
WHERE o.start <= instant <= o.end
RETURN o.percentage
```

// find the max percentage a user has ever owned of any company

```
MATCH (p:Person{name:'Bob Barker'})-[:Owns]->(o:Ownership)
ORDER BY o.percentage DESC
LIMIT 1
WITH o
MATCH (o)-[:OF]->(c:Company)
RETURN c, o.percentage
```

// find who owned what percentages of a company at a point in time

```
WITH {params.instant} as instant
MATCH (o:Ownership)-[:Of]->(c:Company{name:'KripsyKreme'})
WHERE o.start <= instant <= o.end
WITH o
MATCH (p:Person)-[:Owns]->(o)
RETURN p, o.percentage
```

The weakness of this model is that there are bound to be a great many ownership nodes, so queries on ownership from a company or companies may slow depending on how much data you have, but queries of individuals and their ownerships should be comparatively quick.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I am completely new to Neo4j or graph DB. You mentioned that querying FROM a company is slow, is it because it is generally slow to query data that are BEING LINKED TO? Can I simply add a linkage FROM the Ownership node to the Person representing "Being Owned" relationship?

Comment: The direction of the relationship doesn't matter here. My comment about the slowness is due to the amount of data present and needing to be filtered through when querying one way vs another. A single person will likely have very few :Ownership nodes they are linked to, compared to a single company that may have thousands, hundreds of thousands, or even millions of nodes, as it must represent ownership over time over the entire lifetime of the company (depending on how much data is in your system). So queries from a company (or companies) about ownership must touch a much larger subgraph.